# Is it possible to limit CSE search results to pages recommended by social circles?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one, google-custom-search

I'd like to be able to limit CSE search results to only include pages that have been shared or +1'd by people in the current user's Google Plus circles. Is this possible?